# how to get path from database to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

The code is below works well but I want create folder for all each artist but their song doesn't play.

how can I add mp3 path here from db?

```
 jQuery('#main .jp-jplayer').each(function(index) {
                var i = index+1;

                var element = jQuery(this);
                var song ="**/Admin/uploads/mp3/**"+element.find('.path').text(); 
                element.jPlayer({ 
                    ready: function () {
                        jQuery(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                            mp3: song
                        });
                    },

                    preload : "auto",

                    pause : function() {
                        var index = jQuery(this).attr("id");
                        index = index.split("_");
                        index = index[index.length-1];
                        var el = jQuery("#jp_container_"+index);
                        el.find('.jp-progress,.jp-time-holder')
                            .slideToggle();
                    },
                    play: function() { // To avoid both jPlayers playing together.
                        jQuery(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
                        var index = jQuery(this).attr("id");
                        index = index.split("_");
                        index = index[index.length-1];
                        var el = jQuery("#jp_container_"+index);
                        el.find('.jp-progress,.jp-time-holder')
                            .slideToggle();
                    },
                });
            });
```

Comment: What language are you using in your back-end?

Comment: im using asp.net csharp

Comment: Are you using MVC or web forms?  Please post server code.  Also, what doesn't work in the code you posted?

Comment: im using web forms. with this directory song playing good but i want to create folder for all each artist on ftp.  `var song ="/Admin/uploads/mp3/"+element.find('.path').text(); `